# How can I handle Enum based entity in DDD which is supposed to change out of AggregateRoot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, domain-driven-design

In Domin-driven design I'm thinking of a situation in which one specific AggregateRoot has a couple of entities and one of those entities seems like an Enum base entity its values can be updated or added outside of AggregateRoot. Now I'm thinking about how that entity should be addressed in DDD. Should it be just a sub-entity within the AggregateRoot itself ? or should it be on a specific AggregateRoot by itself (Isn't it too small to be an AggregateRoot)?

For example, imagin we have:

```
public class Person: AggregatioRoot
{
    public ICollection<PersonHabit> Habits { get; set; }

    public void AddHabit(Habits habits )
    {
    }
}

public class PersonHabit: Entity
{
    public int HabitName { get; set; }
    public bool StillHave { get; set; }
    public Datetime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

How this situation should be handled? in a way that I can add/Update, PersonHabit records out of the aggregation and at the same time be able to use that?

I know it's possible to have an entity within the AggregateRoot. But in that case, I have to have these behaviors, does it make science in DDD?

```
// Inside Person class
public void AddHabitToPerson(PersonHabit habit)
{
    // Add habit related to this Person
    this.Habits.Add(habit);
}

public void AddHabitIndependently(PersonHabit habit)
{
    // Add habit without any association to a specific Person
}
```

Comment: You have an Entity Database.  The database has tables with each table containing properties.  An Enum in a data base is usually one table with index number in one column and strings in another column.  The reason for the table is the amount of memory the object uses.  The number ID takes less memory than the string name.  Also using this type table is to limit the number of acceptable items in the table.  Entity Migrations will handle adding the table.  But you need to add the rows to the table in code.

Comment: @jdweng It makes sense but my next question is that imagine we have 2 scenarios scenario 1:  when we want to add a record to that entity regardless of the person. scenarion2: when we want to add a record to that entity belonging to the person. should be added both those behaviors in Person class? Does that make science?

Comment: You always add people to the person class.  The person may not belong to any group.  In c# you would have a base class and then inherited classes.  The person may not be in any of the inherited classes.  It would be like having fruits : Red, Blue, Orange, Other.  A banana would be other.